# Is it possible to make a shared function generic?

Tags: vb.net, generics

I can [create classes that use generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y209), however I was wondering if it is possible to apply this to a shared method rather than rely on the caller casting to the correct type.

This is the method:

```
Public Shared Function DeserializeObject(ByVal serializedXml As String, ByVal givenType As System.Type) As Object
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(givenType)
    Return serializer.Deserialize(New IO.StringReader(serializedXml))
End Function
```

I'm pretty sure this can't be done, but thought I'd check (if so Extra points will be awarded if someone can technically explain why the compiler can't do this).. Alternative suggestions would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Shared Function StronglyTypedDeserializeObject(Of T)
       (ByVal serializedXml As String) As T

    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))

    Return DirectCast(
              serializer.Deserialize(New IO.StringReader(serializedXml))
              , T)

End Function
```

Note that invocations will have to supply the type expected:

```
Dim foo As MyType 
    = Utility.StronglyTypedDeserializeObject(Of MyType)(sourceXml)
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason you couldn't create a generic version of the function.  e.g.:

```
Public Shared Function Deserialize(Of T)(ByVal serializedXml As String) As T
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
    Return DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(New StringReader(serializedXml)), T)
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

The Following Example shows how you can do this. The esstential trick is remember that can you can use the GetType function a defined Generic for example GetType(MyObject(Of T))

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Test1 As New MyObject(Of String)
        Dim Test2 As New MyObject(Of Integer)
        Dim Data As String = ""
        Test1.Data = "Hello World"
        Test2.Data = 1010101

        Data = Test1.SerializeObject
        Test1 = MyObject(Of String).DeserializeObject(Data)
        Debug.Print(Test1.Data)

        Data = Test2.SerializeObject
        Test2 = MyObject(Of Integer).DeserializeObject(Data)
        Debug.Print(Test2.Data)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class MyObject(Of T)
    Public Data As T

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function DeserializeObject(ByVal serializedXml As String) As MyObject(Of T)
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(MyObject(Of T)))
        Return serializer.Deserialize(New IO.StringReader(serializedXml))
    End Function

    Public Function SerializeObject() As String
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(MyObject(Of T)))
        Dim Result As New IO.StringWriter()
        serializer.Serialize(Result, Me)
        Return Result.ToString
    End Function
End Class
```

If you don't like fully qualifying the type to get at the shared member then you can do something like this.

```
Public Class MyObjectString
    Inherits MyObject(Of String)
End Class
```

Then you can call MyObjectString.Deserialize

Comment: Sorry, I wanted this for a shared method without an instance of a class. Have you tested this code as you can't called the shared method and referenced a member var from it.

Comment: Just make a new VB Project, add a button to Form1 and past this into Form1.vb and it will run. This is MyObject(Of String).DeserializeObject(Data) calling the Shared Function on the Type. The Type being in this case MyObject(Of String). If you want to use MyObject.DeserializeObject then you are out of luck.